# googleapi admin uploading private application to workspace device

Tags: android, google-api, apk

We have a service account with wide domain delegation, for managing users. We have an internal application, and we would like to create a automated update process. However we can't find documentation or resources about such process.

Is it possible to upload using google api a private apk to all the devices in our workspace ?

(We do not want to use the Google Play Store.)

Comment: where do you want to upload it exactly? what api exactly are you trying to use?

Comment: we wish to install an APK on all device in the workspace.